# Sending push notification to s3 origin website from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lambda

I want to send a websockets notification from lambda function to clients, on a website hosted via s3 origin with cloudfront.

Could someone help me with this, please? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you're trying to solve? Your question is a little unclear to me.

Comment: when a record in a table in database update, i want to send push notification to client site. My frontend is uploaded on s3 and used cloudfornt distribution and my backend is lambda. I use aws rds for database. Thanks

Comment: You need to look at websockets. Here's an example: https://github.com/aws-samples/simple-websockets-chat-app
You'll need to look at how to use CloudFront with multiple origins to route the requests to the Lambda.

Comment: @shearn89 Thanks for your kind help and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at websockets. Here's an example: github.com/aws-samples/simple-websockets-chat-app You'll need to look at how to use CloudFront with multiple origins to route the requests to the Lambda.